# Error when create soft keyboard in android

Tags: java, android, soft-keyboard

Thit is my resource file res/layout/input.xml. My.application - name of my android program

```
<my.application.android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

Android Soft keyboard create  in this:

```
public View onCreateInputView() {
        mInputView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input,
                null);
        Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
        mInputView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        mInputView.setEnabled(true);
        mInputView.setPreviewEnabled(true);
        mInputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        return mInputView;
    }
```

Application compiling without error. When i call my soft keyboard in any android application i get next error:

```
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class my.application.android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at application.my.Keyb.onCreateInputView(Keyb.java:59)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.updateInputViewShown(InputMethodService.java:1073)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindowInner(InputMethodService.java:1428)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindow(InputMethodService.java:1403)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService$InputMethodImpl.showSoftInput(InputMethodService.java:424)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.executeMessage(IInputMethodWrapper.java:188)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:40)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.application.android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView" on path: /data/app/application.my-1.apk
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
12-12 09:07:39.183: E/AndroidRuntime(25341):    ... 18 more
```

Comment: ``Didn't find class "my.application.android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView"`` ??

Comment: have you defined youe activity in manifest ?

Comment: What is your package name? It appears to be different from the one you use in your XML, from your LogCat: `at application.my.Keyb.onCreateInputView(Keyb.java:59)`.

Comment: I believe your ``KeyboardView`` class is nested to another class?

Comment: y dont you refer sample keyboard code provided by google android ?

Comment: Yes, my class declaration -                                       public class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements
  KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener

Answer (score 1):

Try this in manifext file

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="my.application.android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView">
```

You don't need the fully qualified class name. Also if you are working with Eclipse and rename a package go to Project -> Clean and let it clean up your project fixing up references and so on if anything is broken.

Comment: I don't believe `KeyboardView` is an Activity, I believe it is a View.

Comment: I think its activity only, because it cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: My keyboard make as service

Comment: iam having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in manifext file

```
<service
            android:name="SoftKeyboard"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you didnt define servce and permission, paste this in your manifest file

```
<service android:name="SoftKeyboard"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method" />
        </service>
```